# Skobbler web map and iOS Sdk search results are different

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, skmaps

I am using skobbler iOS SDK, 
I see in  [skobbler map in web](http://maps.skobbler.com) show exact search results.

But, in iOS SDK near by search it shows not exact reach results, it shows other irrelevant places also.

How can I get exact search result in iOS SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namebrowser (component responsible for geocoding & search) presented in maps.skobbler.com is not the same with the on in the SDK - it involves 3'rd party components that cannot be sublicensed.

The SDK namebrowser will receive an update in the November/December timeframe, closing a bit more the gap between the 2 components.